# SQL: How to change a row order position

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have this table:

```
ID     Name    position
11     Kate        1
12     Frank       2
13     Anna        3
14     Peter       4
15     James       5
16     Michael     6
```

**Giving the current ID and target position, I need to come up with an efficient way of reordering it.**

I thought of mixing a bit of SQL with my server-side language, eg. (moving up Frank):

```
if (newPosition > oldPosition) {
    UPDATE people SET position = position - 1 WHERE listId = 1 AND position <= @newPosition AND Name != "Frank";
    UPDATE people SET position = @newPos WHERE listId = 1 AND Name="Frank";
} else {
    …
}
```

One of the problems with this is that if the current position is 0, it will go negative.

Any ideas on how to reorder the rows?

EDIT: As an example of what I'm trying to do, let's say I want to move Frank (position = 2) down to between Peter (position = 4) and James (position = 6), so ideally, the table should look like this:

```
ID     Name    position
11     Kate        1
13     Anna        2
14     Peter       3
12     Frank       4
15     James       5
16     Michael     6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear how you intend for the reordering operation to work. Is this what you had in mind?

```
update T
set position =
    case    
        when newPosition > oldPosition then
            case when position = least(oldPosition, newPosition)
                then newPosition else position - 1 end
        else /* newPosition < oldPosition */
            case when position = greatest(oldPosition, newPosition)
                then newPosition else position + 1 end
    end    
where position between
           least(oldPosition, newPosition)
    and greatest(oldPosition, newPosition)
    and oldPosition <> newPosition
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Let's say I want to move Frank (position = 2) down between Peter (position = 4) and James (position = 6). This update statement seems to change Frank's position to 4 (same as James) and no one has position 2 after.

Comment: @Cornwell What values did you use for `oldPosition` and `newPosition`?

Comment: oldPosition = 2; newPosition = 4

Comment: @Cornwell Looks like I had inadvertently swapped the comparisons in the innermost `case`s.

Comment: this works great! Thank you. I was not aware of the case statement. On question, how slow is this query? Could I use it to update a table in real-time when hundreds of users drags rows up and down?

Comment: @Cornwell I'm not sure how the interplay with multiple users will work. That aside, since the bounds of the update are known up front it's probably pretty efficient if you have an index on `position`. Honestly I'm no expert with MySQL tuning so I can't promise anything.